# wpf datagrid extra column in header on left

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I keep getting this button in the header, I can click on the button to select all rows. This misaligns the data from the header. Any ideas? Thanks in Advance.

Datagrid image via link:

http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/CahvlINknhL5ykIW2zCfIw?feat=directlink

```
<dg:DataGrid.Columns>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width=".5*"
                           Binding="{Binding Description}">
    </dg:DataGridTextColumn>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Type}">
    </dg:DataGridTextColumn>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount $" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Amount}">
    </dg:DataGridTextColumn>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Effective From Date" Width="100" Binding="{Binding EffectiveFromDate}"
                           IsReadOnly="True">
    </dg:DataGridTextColumn>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Effective To Date" Width="100" Binding="{Binding EffectiveToDate}"
                           IsReadOnly="True">
    </dg:DataGridTextColumn>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Status}">
    </dg:DataGridTextColumn>
</dg:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"

WPFToolKit Version: 3.5.40128.1

Odd, that excatly  what I thought at first but now its just really annoying... I don't get it!! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 61):

I am sure you have figured this out by now but try setting this Property in your data grid.

```
HeadersVisibility="Column"
```

Comment: That was superb solution. It solved my problem of extra column on left in datagrid.. Great job!!!!!!!!

Comment: That was so easy. I spent more time that I would like say looking for extra garbage in the xaml bits and this fixed it all.  Keep up the good work.

Comment: This answer helped me alot. I was getting a column at the extreme right and nothing was working. I wish I could have selected it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. If I just take your code and paste into an empty `DataGrid` element, I don't get that behavior.

What does your `DataGrid` element definition look like?

Also, what version of the WPF Toolkit are you using?

Comment: xmlns:dg="schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/
WPFToolKit Version: 3.5.40128.1 
Odd, that excatly what I thought at first but now its just really annoying... I don't get it!! thanks for the help

Comment: I am seeing the same thing in the Feb 2010 toolkit and the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. It can occur when your application defines a default style for button with a minimum width.

The solution is to not show the row headers or to change the default button style.

Answer (score 0):

set rowHeadersVisible = false this should remove the extra column in the datagrid on the left